# Program crash cause screen freeze

Tags: freeze, 19.10

I've been experiencing some issues with Ubuntu 19.10, where a program suddenly crashes which cause the entire screen to freeze. Last time it was Firefox that crashed, however I am uncertain if this was what happened the previous times. However, I got an error message that the program is unresponsive and a prompt to force shutdown, but I am unable to click on anything. The mouse cursor can be moved around, but when I try click on anything nothing happens. This has happened a few times now, and the only way to get out of it is to reboot. (This is of course less than ideal, since it interrupts my work flow and I can potentially lose any unsaved progress.)

Is this a known issue with a solution? ..or is it a least a way to kill whatever process that crashes without rebooting?

Comment: The desktop knows how to handle a mere application crash. A "screen freeze" usually means a crash of the kernel or some element of the display stack which is unlikely to be recoverable. Check your /var/crash directory for a .crash file matching the correct time of crash. If there isn't one, then you likely have a kernel crash. Crashes are not considered a  single "issue". Each *cause* of a crash is usually considered a bug. If you are able to determine the (reproducible) cause of a crash, please report it to the bug tracker so it can be fixed. Note that frequent crashes are NOT common.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Here's the first:
`$ ls -al /var/crash
totalt 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 nov.  23 07:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root     4096 okt.  25 15:32 ..`

Comment: @heynnema The second:

`$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
totalt 24
drwxr-xr-x 6 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 sep.  25 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 nov.  28 00:13 ..
drwxrwxr-x 7 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 sep.  25 13:12 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
drwxr-xr-x 2 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 sep.  23 14:17 pidgin-conversation-integration@kagesenshi.org
drwxr-xr-x 4 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 sep.  23 14:16 pidgin@muffinmad
drwxr-xr-x 2 nord06019185 nord06019185 4096 sep.  23 14:18 pidgin-persistent-notification@ikkoku.de`

Comment: @heynnema The third:

`free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       3,0Gi        10Gi       136Mi       2,0Gi        12Gi
Swap:          19Gi          0B        19Gi`

Comment: Go to `https://extensions.gnome.org/local/` and temporarily disable ALL extensions. (note: if this page appears blank, there's a current problem that should work itself out at a later date/time). Reboot. Then see if the problem still occurs. Report back.